How exactly does the Lint Trap of a top-loading washing machine work and can I improve it?
For over 20 years I always had the impression that the Lint Traps in top-loading washing machines do not ensure, anyhow, that all flow of water during the draining must pass through it.
And I've also suffered with excess of lint in their discharge, which only reinforced my belief that they don't work properly.
Today I just verified this, and really, the trap is located above the bottom of the inner tub even, and water has other paths to pass without going through it.
When filling, as in the picture below shows, you can see water in the bottom of the inner tub, and it didn't even reach the bottom of the hole where the trap sits.

When full, water basically has 3 paths to go from the inner to the outer tub, where it's drained: Through the holes in the inner tub (light blue arrows), through the space between the agitator and the bottom of the inner tub (red arrows) and the holes on the agitator (green arrows).
Only the water flowing through the holes of the agitator (green arrows) pass through the Lint Trap.
Plus, in the end of draining, the only path left is the space between the agitator and the tub, as the other holes end before that level, so after that moment water doesn't even pass through the trap anymore.
So how exactly can it be efficient for anything?
Is it considering the clothes themselves will trap lint in the bottom? But what about lint going through the holes in the tub, when the level is higher?
Is there any way I can filter the lint better from the discharge?
In the (rented) studio apartment where I live the discharge has to go to the sink, and when there's too much lint it can clog it. Is there any reliable way to add another trap/filter here?
As it is there's no other filter nor trap here, I already checked, below the washing machine there's no filter before or after the water pump, it goes directly to the sewer.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement, but about the design of an appliance.

@RMDman Actually, it is if there's some feasible solution to improve the lint trapping, as I more than once had issues with excess of lint in its discharge.

You can add a lint filter to the sink itself.  This can be something that goes in the drain.  Example.
You can add a lint filter to the end of the hose that drains into the sink.  Example.
Examples are just the first matches from searching.  No endorsement intended.  I have no idea if those are more or less effective than other examples.  Also may not be the correct size.  Just examples of what I'm describing.
I suspect that the problem you're noting is that the lint trap in the washing machine isn't there to prevent lint from getting out of the washing machine but to provide an easy place to clean lint out of the machine.  I.e. the washing machine would like the lint to leave the machine.  The trap is to catch lint that is not leaving so that you can remove it.  From that perspective, lint going out the drain is good for the machine even if it is bad for the plumbing.
The landlord could help fix this by installing a dedicated standpipe for the washing machine.  That would stop lint clogging the sink entirely and if properly installed, would drain the lint better.  The landlord is responsible for maintaining the plumbing almost always.  If the landlord does not want to take responsibility, you could contact a lawyer for further options.
